# How are size= and linewidth= related in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not understanding the relationships between `size=` and `linewidth=` in points, lines, and text in `ggplot2`. Below I try to demonstrate my confusion.

In [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html) tidyverse documentation about aesthetic specifications the following statements are made:

- re: lines (under "Linewidth" subheading).

> Due to a historical error, the unit of linewidth is roughly 0.75 mm.
> Making it exactly 1 mm would change a very large number of existing
> plots, so we’re stuck with this mistake.

- re: points (under "Colour and Fill" subheading)

> The size of the filled part is controlled by size, the size of the
> stroke is controlled by stroke. Each is measured in mm, and the total
> size of the point is the sum of the two.

- re: text (under "Font size" subheading)

> The size of text is measured in mm. This is unusual, but makes the
> size of text consistent with the size of lines and points.

Given these it seems that all three are measured in mm. [Side note: except when `size=` is used in `element_text()` where the units are pts.] My interpretation of this language though is that for the same `size=` and `linewidth=` that text and points (actually `size=`+`stroke=`) should be the same size, but lines will be smaller due to the "historical error."

However, my experiment below does not support this.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1,linewidth=20) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(x=0.5,y=1,label="Text"),
            mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,label=label),
            size=20,color="red") +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0.4,y=1),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y),
             pch=21,size=10,stroke=10,fill="red",color="blue") +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0.6,y=1),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y),
             pch=21,size=20,stroke=0,fill="orange") +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0.7,y=1),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y),
             pch=21,size=0,stroke=20,color="green") +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=0.8,y=1),mapping=aes(x=x,y=y),
             pch=21,size=10,stroke=10*0.75,fill="orange",color="green") +
  scale_x_continuous(limit=c(0.35,0.85)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

It seems that ...

- My text and line are the same height ... I expected the line to be smaller.
- My blue and red point is larger than the line and the text ... I expected it to be the same as the text.
- My orange point (just `size=`) and green point (just `stroke=`) are not the same size ... I expected them to be equal given that `size=`+`stroke=` gives the "size" of the point.
- My orange and green point equals the orange point (not sure anymore what I expected here).

Thoughts on what I am missing here? Thanks.

p.s., I did ask this same question on [Posit Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/units-of-linewidth/162885/2) but received only one reply that really did not help to allay my confusion.

Comment: If you are looking for the next layer down then look for the function ggpar(). Ggplot is built on top of the same mechanism as the lattice package, namely the grid package.

Answer (score 5):

Could be a bug. Or this is by intention and I miss something.

I have had a look at `GeomPoint$draw_panel`. For the `pointsGrob` the `fontsize` and the `lwd` for the symbols are given/computed as

```
fontsize = coords$size * .pt + stroke_size * .stroke/2
lwd = coords$stroke * .stroke/2
```

where `.pt = 2.845276` whereas `.stroke = 3.779528`. Hence, different conversion are applied for `size` and `stroke` and IMHO this is the reason why the size of the points does not add to `size+stroke` as stated in the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#colour-and-fill-1) even if this is hardly visible for small point sizes.

This could also be "confirmed" by adding a correction factor to the stroke, i.e. by multiplying by `.pt / .stroke`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(.4, .6, .7, .8),
  size = c(10, 20, 0, 10),
  stroke = c(10, 0, 20, 10),
  fill = c("red", "orange", "black", "orange"),
  color = c("blue", "black", "green", "green")
)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c("Without correction", "With correction"), linewidth = 20) +
  scale_fill_identity(aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  scale_x_continuous(limit = c(0.35, 0.85)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text())

p +
  geom_point(
    data = dat, mapping = aes(
      x = x, y = "Without correction",
      size = size, stroke = stroke,
      fill = fill, color = color
    ),
    pch = 21
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = dat, mapping = aes(
      x = x, y =  "With correction",
      size = size, stroke = stroke * .pt / .stroke,
      fill = fill, color = color
    ),
    pch = 21
  )
```

[image]

Another example of the issue based on the example in the docs:

```
sizes <- expand.grid(size = seq(0, 30, 3) * 2, stroke = seq(0, 30, 3) * 2) |>
  subset(size + stroke == 30)

ggplot(sizes, aes(x = size, size = size)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c("Without correction", "With correction"), colour = "white", linewidth = 30) +
  geom_point(aes(y = "Without correction", stroke = stroke), shape = 21, fill = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = "With correction", stroke = stroke * .pt / .stroke), shape = 21, fill = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.1, 0)) +
  scale_size_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Your `.pt/.stroke` correction equals 0.7528, which seems like the "roughly 0.75 mm" mentioned in the docs for `linewidth=`. Thus, is it that `linewidth=`, `size=` for points, and `size=` for text are all scaled to "roughly 0.75 mm", but `stroke=` is scaled to 1 mm??